# send a nested request in android\

Tags: java, android, soap

how do call a web srvice using soap when my webservice is like this.. i need to fill up the cus details how can i do that .. can any one guide me on this

```
<registerCustomer xmlns="http://webservices.foodtruck.zsl.com/">
  <cusDetails>
    <FirstName>string</FirstName>
    <LastName>string</LastName>
    <EmailID>string</EmailID>
    <AddLine1>string</AddLine1>
    <AddLine2>string</AddLine2>
    <ZipCode>string</ZipCode>
    <City>string</City>
    <StateCode>string</StateCode>
    <PhoneNumber>string</PhoneNumber>
    <Username>string</Username>
    <Password>string</Password>
    <BrandID>int</BrandID>
    <DiscAgree>int</DiscAgree>
    <Latitude>string</Latitude>
    <Longitude>string</Longitude>
  </cusDetails>
       </registerCustomer>
       </soap:Body>
     </soap:Envelope>
```

The code which i use to call the service:
    final String METHOD_NAME = ServiceStrings.registerMethod;
        final String SOAP_ACTION = ServiceStrings.registerSoapAction;
        try {

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

        pi.setName("cusDetails");
        pi.setValue(new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "cusDetails")
        .addProperty("FirstName", fname)
        .addProperty("LastName", lname)
        .addProperty("EmailID", email)
        .addProperty("AddLine1", add1)
        .addProperty("AddLine2", add2)
        .addProperty("ZipCode", zip)
        .addProperty("City", city)
        .addProperty("StateCode", state)
        .addProperty("PhoneNumber", phoneno)
        .addProperty("Username", email)
        .addProperty("Password", pwd)
        .addProperty("BrandID", 1)
        .addProperty("DiscAgree", 1)
        .addProperty("Latitude", "11.2")
        .addProperty("Longitude", "11.2"));

        request.addProperty(pi);
```

But i get an error

```
Server was unable to read request. ---&gt; There is an error in XML document (1, 316). ---&gt; The specified type was not recognized: name='cusDetails', namespace='http://webservices.foodtruck.zsl.com/', at &lt;cusDetails xmlns='http://webservices.foodtruck.zsl.com/'&gt;
```

Comment: you somehow send `&lt;` / `&gt;` instead of `<` `>`

Comment: i given my full code.. i didnt mention anything like &lt; / &gt; then how does it hpnd

Comment: Something does not work while constructing or sending the xml `<cusDetails>` -> `&lt;cusDetails&gt;`. But I don't know how `SoapObject` works.

Comment: Try the AndroidSOAP project... :) http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home

Comment: Please verify this sample too:
http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("cusDetails");
        pi.setValue(new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Customer")
                .addProperty("FirstName", fname)
                .addProperty("LastName", lname)
                .addProperty("EmailID", email)
                .addProperty("AddLine1", add1)
                .addProperty("AddLine2", add2).addProperty("ZipCode", zip)
                .addProperty("City", city).addProperty("StateCode", state)
                .addProperty("PhoneNumber", phoneno)
                .addProperty("Username", email)
                .addProperty("Password", pwd)
                .addProperty("BrandID", brandid)
                .addProperty("DiscAgree", flag)
                .addProperty("Latitude", "11.2")
                .addProperty("Longitude", "11.2"));

        request.addProperty(pi);
        Log.e("req", brandid);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(
                URL);
```